# Override Magento Core Abstract Controller

Tags: overrides, controllers

I want to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` in my module `Mycompany_Mymodule`.

I've searched the net,but I couldn't find anyway to do this. Is it like the controllers, or it has a different way?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Pls have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374344/how-can-i-override-a-magento-controller

Comment: thanks for the link, but it is about **controllers** folder, but I am talking about **Controller** folder, I mean the abstract controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override that controller.
Well...actually you can but it will have no effect.
The `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` class is never instantiated. It is there as a common parent class for the rest of the admin controllers.
even if you find a way to rewrite it all the other admin controllers will extend the original class so your modification will be useless.

If you want to change something in it you have to copy it to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php` and make your modifications there.

Here are more details about why [you cannot rewrite some classes in Magento](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2011/09/why-cant-you-override-some-classes-in.html)

Comment: i dont think there should be ever a need to override abstract class in magento(correct me if i am wrong)..as u mentioned factory method access classes which are extended from abstract classes(not all of course!) so these methods can always be extendable.